# I want to convert SVG to DWG is there any software / library which can help

Tags: .net, cad, svg

I need to convert SVG images to CAD readable file DWG/DXF is there any software or library which can help.

Budget and programming language is not an issue, though a .Net based product will be great.

Comment: Programming language? Price? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.